# Build SQL Select object in Laminas that cotains subquery as FROM table

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, laminas-api-tools, laminas

I'm trying to put that query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM table1)
  UNION 
  (SELECT * FROM table2)
) AS t;
```

into **\Laminas\Db\Sql\Select** object. Something like this:

```
$select1 = new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Select($table1); // this is select for table1
$select2 = new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Select($table2); // this is select for table2

$select1->combine($select2);
```

So far everything looks good, and query is fine, but while I'm trying to use that query as a table, like this:

```
$selectUnion = new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Select();
$selectUnion->from($select1->getSqlString());
```

I'm getting very strange, and wrong query, result of

```
echo $selectUnion->getSqlString();
```

is:

```
SELECT "((SELECT * FROM table1) UNION (SELECT * FROM table2))";
```

which is wrong, because **FROM** part is missing and also **"** are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by editing **\Laminas\Db\Sql\Select** class from line 199:

```
if (! is_string($table) && ! is_array($table) && ! $table instanceof TableIdentifier) {
        throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(
            '$table must be a string, array, or an instance of TableIdentifier'
        );
    }
```

by adding possibility to object of $from can be of type Select, which is natively supported by Laminas:

```
if (! is_string($table) && ! is_array($table) && ! ($table instanceof TableIdentifier || $table instanceof Select)) {
        throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(
            '$table must be a string, array, or an instance of TableIdentifier or Select'
        );
    }
```

Now to build SELECT from another SELECT we have two possibilities:

```
$selectUnion = new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Select();
$selectUnion->from(['t' => $select1->getSqlString()]);
```

or

```
$selectUnion = new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Select();
$selectUnion->columns(['*'], false);
$selectUnion->from($select1->getSqlString());
```

Because our Select needs to have either alias name for subselect or disabled auto prefixation of table columns.

Comment: I think this is not correct .. it already works out of the box like this:

 "->from(['r' => $otherSelect])"

a "select from select" always needs an alias.